# httpd.conf proxypass rewrite

Tags: apache, proxypass

I am trying to use the proxy only if the request comes from VLC player, so in the request header the user-agent would contain VLC.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/mvs">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} -strmatch '*VLC*'"
RewriteRule ^mvs/(.*)$  http://www.example.com/directory/$1  [P]
ProxyPassReverse /mvs/ http://www.example.com/directory/
</Directory>
```

When I run a file in VLC web plugin which is located in /var/www/html/mvs/ it plays, so I think that the RewriteRule and the RewriteCond are wrong. The file should not play because the file does not exist on the http://www.example.com/directory/ folder. I don't know how to debug this. Sry

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: The code is not working..

Comment: I am not trying to give you a hard time, but you should edit your question so that it includes either the error or the incorrect results that you are getting from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I wrote the following lines in the .htaccess file placed in the html directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^VLC
RewriteRule  ^mvs(.*) http://188.25.221.87$1 [R,L]
```

If the user-agent contains VLC, and tries to access the /html/mvs/ directory he is being redirected to `http://188.25.221.87/` and the path or query after /mvs/ is copied. If the user agent does not contain VLC the user is not redirected. Important  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^ is case sensitive, so it would not have worked with ^vlc.